# Right-align CSS counters in ::before pseudo-element

Tags: html, css

I'm using CSS counters and the `<code>` tag to show syntax highlighted code snippets with automatically generated line numbers:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zXsXU/)

HTML:

```
<code>
 <div class="line"><span>line 1</span></div>
 <div class="line"><span>line 2</span></div>
 ...
</code>
```

CSS:

```
code {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px black solid;
    padding: 1em;
    font-family: "Consolas", "Monaco", "Courier New", monospace;

    counter-reset: line;
}

code .line {
    display: block;

    counter-increment: line;
}

code .line::before {
    border-right: 1px black solid;
    padding-right: 1em;
    margin-right: 1em;

    content: counter(line);
}
```

It works well up to 9 lines, but once it hits two digits, it gets out of alignment:

[image: css counters]

How can I make the left edges of the lines align? Or right-align the line numbers?

I've already tried:

- `counter(line, decimal-leading-zero)` - it works up to 99 lines, but it breaks at 100, and I don't like the way it looks
- Altering the content with JavaScript, but `getComputedStyle(line, '::before').content` just returns `"counter(line)"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `display:inline-block;` and a `width` based on your practical needs:

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/zXsXU/14/

```
code .line::before {
    display:inline-block;
    width:2em;
    border-right: 1px black solid;
    padding-right: 1em;
    margin-right: 1em;
    content: counter(line);
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly! I'm also using `text-align: right` and a `code.long` class for longer snippets which increases the width available for the numbers.

Comment: Glad to be of help to you!